# Prevent page reload in cordova apps

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

Some of my app users report the app gets restarted (reloaded in crosswalk webview) after being in background for some time.

My best guess is that insufficient device memory can cause this. Is there anyway to prevent that, so my app can keep it's state until closed?

Comment: did u get solution for this ?

Comment: @rashidnk Nope, although I get less reports like that, devices get more RAM and I do better memory management.

Comment: I tested my Cordova app on Samsung s5  that reloads when it retrieves from background , but in some other phones which has Android 5.0 it resumes, no issue